# Default argument depending of the function matched in R

Tags: r, function, default-value

Currently, I have two very similar wrappers around `table()` and `xtabs()`:

```r
mytable <- function(..., useNA = "ifany") {
  tab <- table(..., useNA = useNA)
  # additional manipulations
  tab
}

mytable(warpbreaks[-1])

myxtabs <- function(..., na.action = NULL, addNA = TRUE) {
  tab <- xtabs(..., na.action = na.action, addNA = addNA)
  # same manipulations as in mytable
  tab
}

myxtabs(breaks ~ ., warpbreaks)
```

Since most code is duplicated, I wish to combine both wrappers into a single one. A simple solution is:

```r
newfun <- function(..., fun) {
  fun <- match.fun(fun)
  tab <- fun(...)
  # same manipulations as in mytable
  tab
}

newfun(warpbreaks[-1], fun = table)
newfun(breaks ~ ., warpbreaks, fun = xtabs)
```

However, can I specify default arguments depending of the function that is matched? i.e.:

- if `fun = table`, set `useNA = "ifany"`;
- or if `fun = xtabs`, set `na.action = NULL` and `addNA = TRUE`.

In addtion, what is the "recommanded" way to restrict `fun` to only `table()` and `xtabs()`? I guess I have many ways to achieve this (`stopifnot()`, `if () {}`/`else {}`, `switch()`, `match.arg()`), but I am looking for good practice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Try redefining table and xtabs in newfun.  Ensure that fun is calling the local versions by converting it to character and using do.call.

```
newfun <- function(..., fun) {
  table <- function(x, ..., useNA = "ifany") base::table(x, ..., useNA = useNA)
  xtabs <- function(x, ..., na.action = NULL, addNA = NULL)
      stats::xtabs(x, ..., na.action = na.action, addNA = addNA)
  fun <- deparse(substitute(fun))
  do.call(fun, list(...))
}

newfun(warpbreaks[-1], fun = table)
newfun(breaks ~ ., warpbreaks, fun = xtabs)
```

**2)** Another approach is to have 3 functions, one for your version of table, one for your version of xtabs and then one to contain the common code which each of the others would call.  That may be more straight forward than (1).

```
mytable <- function(..., useNA = "ifany") {
  tab <- table(..., useNA = useNA)
  other(tab)
  tab
}
  
myxtabs <- function(..., na.action = NULL, addNA = TRUE) {
  tab <- xtabs(..., na.action = na.action, addNA = addNA)
  other(tab)
  tab
}

other <- function(x) {
  # code
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly! Small typo: `addNA = NULL` should be `addNA = TRUE`. In addition, do you have any advice how to restrict `fun` only to `table` and `xtabs`? Is `stopifnot(identical(fun, table) | identical(fun, xtabs))` good enough? Finally, is there any benefits of `deparse(substitute(fun))` over `match.fun`?

Comment: Try `stopfinot(fun %in% c("table", "xtabs"))` .  match.fun(fun) won't work since it will use the original function.  We want to use the local function of the same name.

Comment: Thank you very much again! However, I get `Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 'match' requires vector arguments`. Do you have another idea? Ideally, I wish not to provide `fun` as a name.

Comment: It has to be placed AFTER fun has been converted to character.  Have added (2).